# typing an eventlistenner on vanilla + typescript

Tags: typescript

how can i type correctly so my event listenner has access to target.value for example in typescript + vanilla js?

I did some tests with MouseEvent, HTMLButtonElement and I can't get a result.

```js
const Database = {
  createDataKeys() {
    const dataKeys = Object.keys(database);

    return dataKeys.map((spot) => {
      const newBtn = document.createElement('button');

      newBtn.innerText = spot;

      newBtn.addEventListener('click', (e: MouseEvent) => {
        console.log(e.target.);
      });
      return newBtn;
    });
  }
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to narrow it down, not every target has a value !

```
  newBtn.addEventListener('click', (e: MouseEvent) => {
    if (e.target instanceof HTMLInputElement) {
      console.log(e.target.value);
    }
  });
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAJgQyggRgiBTGBeGBvAXwG4BYAKHNElgBElV0tc9yYZgAnDJDO5AaQwBPCAAoAlPlZt24aPHqCROGAHkUAKwzAoAOgDWwsYmRpM40hTIyYXKAFcOYBQKO6AtggAOo0RC8gUJLYAHxS1jay1DBgGADuAEJQzrhwIMD27hhgepzcUBgAogA2GFk5ogDkKPZQUOCVFuTSNrGJyboAlmCxHAAqGAAesLj%20gZYtMm1JYLoIcHCFAG7ZUAAyndDZGBxVwMWdwPqVADQwohgAXDAAsiD2mMurwWEsEZEwnQBm5xi6yBwAOYYWDdaAIMDADAgH4ACT6NzWAEkwF5aiUys9wh8bFQICBSrpiiBARd-gggSDdEsEMV7Bgmu9IgRJmwCIyPnZHM5pslLDZ2fyYCyyMQgA)

Comment: that's a bit confused but solve my problem. ty

Comment: [Narrowing](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html) is one of the great features of Typescript !